# syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: bash, scripts, syntax

I was writing a bash script where I faced the below error and I have no idea about the reason:

`` syntax error near unexpected token `fi' ``

my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ 5 -gt 1 ]; than
echo "Hello world"
fi
```

Comment: Welcome to ask ubuntu !!! You should accept the answer if you find it useful , Micheal H 's answer was helpful right ? Click on that up arrow button and tick it as accepted , So that he would get some reputation points for his answer and efforts .

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if [ 5 -gt 1 ]
then
echo "Hello world"
fi
```

Comment: thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

You mistyped the keyword "then".

Comment: opppss xD
thanks a lot